# Some prototyping with google maps infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm new here in SO and i have a lil question about... well, I don't know exactly what is wrong with this, so I hope that you could give me some clues. I hope to don't bore you, so let's start.

I've made a prototyped "class method" (using [this](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/)). It works perfectly.

Then, I've start to code my GoogleMap "Class" like this

```
var map = Class.extend({

init: function(){
    this.mystyles = [
    {
        featureType: "all",
        elementType: "labels",
        stylers: [
        {
            visibility: "off"
        }
        ]
    }
    ];
    this.myoptions= {
        zoom: 12,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(10.24462, -67.59374199999999),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        styles: this.mystyles
    }
    this.markerSucursal = new Array();
    this.infoWindow = new Array();
},

initializeMap: function(divElemento){
    this.objMap = new google.maps.Map(divElemento,this.myoptions);

},

preloadMarkers: function(jsonArray){

    for(var k in jsonArray) {
        var localizacion= new google.maps.LatLng(jsonArray[k].coordenada_x,jsonArray[k].coordenada_y);
        var marker= new google.maps.Marker({
            position: localizacion,
            map: this.objMap
        })
        this.markerSucursal[k] = marker;
    }
},

createDialogs: function(jsonArray){        
    for(var k in jsonArray) {
        var marker = this.markerSucursal[k];
        var contentDialog = "<div><p><strong>Testing testing</strong></p></div>"
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content : contentDialog
        })
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
            infowindow.open(this.objMap,marker)
        })
        this.infoWindow[k] = infowindow
    }
}});
```

show the map [Check]

show the markers [Check]

show the infowindow at clicking []

What could be wrong here? If you need more information or code please tell me.

Comment: Any errors in the javascript console?

Comment: nop, nothing... everything clear

Comment: ok, after a loooooooong nap, i've notice that the click listener is not working... i will try to make it work, probably that is the main problem

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it... i'm really sorry about the messy and dumb question, but i made everything work...

the thing is that i was reffering to the context "this" inside the google.maps.event.addListener function... inside the inner function, i couldnt refer to the parent function methods (like this.objmap or this.markerSucursal). Dont forget that i was coding inside a prototype **method** before calling the google.map object

just for the record, the answer to myself (and for everyone else who has this issue) is like this (i'll only show the createDialog and preloadMarkers Methods)

```
preloadMarkers: function(jsonArray){

    var objMap = this.objMap // the initializeMap method sets this object

    for(var k in jsonArray) {
        var localization= new google.maps.LatLng(jsonArray[k].coordenada_x,jsonArray[k].coordenada_y);
        var marker= new google.maps.Marker({
            position: localizacion,
            map: objMap
        })

        this.markerSucursal[k] = marker;
    }
},


createDialog: function(jsonArray){        

    for(var k in jsonArray) {

        var marker = this.markerSucursal[k]
        var objMap = this.objMap
        contentDialog = "<div> <p>testing testing</p> </div>"

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentDialog
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(objMap,marker);
        });
    }
}
```

And thats it... works like charm :)

Again, thanks a lot for reading, sorry for the bad english and greetings from Venezuela!